# Google Cloud SQL I/O Overage?

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine

I have been looking everywhere I can think of and can't seem to find the answer to this. How does Google Cloud SQL account for overages? For example, their smallest instance is the D0 package that allows I/O of 200k per day. What happens when an instance reaches that limit?

Does Google charge an increased rate for overages, are you locked out of I/O (Access) for the day, do they bump you another 200K and charge you an extra $0.36?

I was reading their pricing tier here but they don't mention anything about overages: https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-sql/#pricing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk I/O overage is charged the same as per use disk I/O. The current price is $0.1 per million disk I/O operations.

Let's say your D0 instance has used 300k I/O operations for the day. The extra 100k I/O operations will incur a cost of $0.1, since it'll be rounded up to the nearest million for billing purposes.

Comment: Thanks, Tony. Is there a table/page that references this?

Comment: Tony,again thanks for your response. I was able to finally find a table that is more defined than the table in the previous link. https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/pricing

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better table that defines pricing in detail https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/pricing